# Как задать параметры длины, ширины и позиции картинки svg через js?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, svg

Можно ли для этой картинки прописать параметры длины ширины и позиции в js? как это можно реализовать?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>


    <script type="text/javascript">


document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = "<img src = https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/America_Online_logo.svg> "  ;

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так например:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>


    <script type="text/javascript">


document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = "<img style = 'width : 100px ; heigth : 50px ; position: relative' src = https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/America_Online_logo.svg> "  ;

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: calc(50vh - 50px) calc(50vw - 50px) 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    
    img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: calc(50vh - 50px) calc(50vw - 50px) 0;
}
</head>

<body>


    <script type="text/javascript">


document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = "<img style = 'width : 100px ; heigth : 50px ; position: relative' src = https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/America_Online_logo.svg> "  ;

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```